# Input data reactivity freezes in Shiny module

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

When executing module innerDemo function (see code below), input data is not correctly reflected in the result displayed. I executed innerDemo() and was expecting displayed data field to reflect exactly what I typed in Quantity field. But displayed data field stopped moving according to entry at some point (see picture).
So it seems that reactivity stopped working after some time.
Either the code below is flawed or my R configuration is not correct. I run latest versions of R and Shiny though.
Also I follow the latest module code skeleton format (as per "Mastering Shiny" book) but all questions and answers on this forum use the older module code skeleton format (with callModule), so I am confused.

[Innerdemo execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sMP4.png)

```
library(shiny)

innerUI <- function(id) {
    tagList(
        numericInput(NS(id,"Qty"),label="Quantity:",value=0)
  )
}

innerServer <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input,output,session) {
        data <- reactive({input$Qty})
        print(paste0("Data:Qty ",data()))
        return(data)
    })
}

innerDemo <- function() {
    ui <- fluidPage(
        innerUI("Ex1"),
        tableOutput("Ex")
    )
    server <- function(input,output,session) {
        output$Ex <- renderTable(innerServer("Ex1")())
    }
  
    shinyApp(ui,server)
}
```

R.version shows R4.2.2, shiny version is 1.7.4 and all dependencies are up to date.

Thanks for any idea,
Alexis

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use your module-server-function repeatedly inside a reactive expression as in

```r
renderTable({ innerServer("Ex1")() })
```

Instead, a module-server-function should be called once when the app starts and then do it's duties going forward. This can be archieved by returning a reactive data object that can be used in reactive expressions of the main server.

```r
library(shiny)

mod_ui <- function(id) {
  numericInput(NS(id, "qty"), label = "Quantity:", value = 0)
}

mod_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    return( reactive({input$qty}) )
  })
}

app_demo <- function() {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    mod_ui("mod"),
    tableOutput("table")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    mod_data <- mod_server("mod")
    output$table <- renderTable({ data.frame(x = mod_data()) })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui,server)
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `renderTable()` inside `mod_server()` and display it as part of `module_ui()`. That depends on your usecase.

Comment: Thank you very much Gregor, it works fine now. Looks like reactivity is hard to grasp!